# Spree Relation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to add product attachment functionality to a Spree store. E.g. a `product` has many attached `documents`: brochures, instruction manuals, etc. I can't get the relationship between documents and products to work.

I can use the Paperclip gem for the attachment functionality since Spree already uses it for images.

I have the "document" model: `models/spree/document.rb`:

```
class Spree::Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :products, class_name: "Spree::Product"
  has_attached_file :pdf
end
```

Then I try to relate the document model to the `Spree::Product` model in `models/spree/product_decorator.rb`:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then I add migrations:

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spree_documents do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddPdfToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :spree_documents, :pdf
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :spree_documents, :pdf
  end
end
```

Now I go into the rails console to see if it worked:

```
#=> prod = Spree::Product.first
#=> prod.document
#=> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column spree_documents.product_id does not exist
#=> LINE 1: ..."spree_documents".* FROM "spree_documents"  WHERE "spree_doc...
                                                             ^
#=> : SELECT "spree_documents".* FROM "spree_documents"  WHERE "spree_documents"."product_id" = $1
```

Seems like I'm not defining the relationship between documents and products correctly, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never added a `product_id` column to your `Spree::Documents` table. When you define a model `belongs_to` another model, it tells ActiveRecord that the first one will be a `[relation]_id` column in its table.

You just need to make sure to add `t.references :product` in your migration, so it'd look like:

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spree_documents do |t|
      t.references :product
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```